# Support Special Characters in WordPress

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, wordpress

I recently figure out the problem of supporting special characters in post or plugin.
I find this problem when i try to add the latin word it display `?` as output. I googled a lot to conclude the problem has in

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

  /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
 //define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

So I just commented this and checked it working. `ŠĐĆČŽ` When i again undo the comment it returns  `?` mark. 
Which is the best way inorder to support special characters in wordpress post or page or plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Wordpress uses UTF-8 in its databases, so it already has support for Unicode characters. Your problem is likely to come from improper handling of encodings - give more detail about what you are doing, and check out [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: Hi @Pekka웃 Thanks for your reply. How can i make support special characters with character set of utf8.